# git-shell - New repositories

Tags: git, repository, git-shell

I have a server with a dedicated `git` user and repositories
I'm trying to use the [`git-shell` method](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server) to allow my devs to work on several projects.

I'm about to change the shell of my `git` user to `git-shell`
If I do that, I won't be able to connect with a standard shell anymore (that's the idea).

**Question**: So how will I create new repositories ?

Will I have each time to connect with a sudoer and create the repo then chown it ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Will I have each time to connect with a sudoer and create the repo then chown it ?

Yes, you can see an example in the article "[Git Local Repository Setup Guide](https://github.com/alghanmi/ubuntu-desktop_setup/wiki/Git-Local-Repository-Setup-Guide)" by [Rami Al-Ghanmi (`alghanmi`)](https://github.com/alghanmi):

### Repository Setup & Essentials

> First, we create the git user and set the account up for SSH Public Key Authentication and no terminal login.
>   That means, the git account can not login using a password (only via PKA) and has no regular shell access. **Instead, it will be using a special git shell with a limited set of commands**.

```
#Create git user account
sudo adduser --shell $(which git-shell) --gecos 'git version control' --disabled-password git

#Add git user to the appropriate groups
sudo usermod -a -G www-data git
sudo usermod -a -G developers git

#Setup authorized_keys file for access
sudo mkdir -p /home/git/.ssh
sudo touch /home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys
sudo chmod 600 /home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys
sudo chmod 700 /home/git/.ssh

#Copy the git-shell-commands to get limited shell access
sudo cp -r /usr/share/doc/git/contrib/git-shell-commands /home/git/
sudo chmod 750 /home/git/git-shell-commands/*

#Fix permissions
sudo chown -R git:git /home/git/
```

> Add your [SSH generated key](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys#platform-linux) to the authorized key list. You can repeat this step for all users you wish to give access to

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | sudo tee -a /home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

> Allow the git user to access the system via SSH

```
echo "AllowUsers git" | sudo tee -a /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sudo service ssh restart
```

> Create a location to store repositories

```
sudo mkdir -p /home/repo
sudo chown -R git:www-data /home/repo
```

### Create a HelloWorld Repository

```
#Create the directory (always end with .git)
sudo mkdir /home/repo/helloworld.git
cd /home/repo/helloworld.git
#Initialize a bare repository
sudo git --bare init

#Some meta-data
echo "Hello World Repository. Testing system configuration" | sudo tee /home/repo/helloworld.git/description
echo "[gitweb]" | sudo tee -a /home/repo/helloworld.git/config
echo -e "\towner = \\"Rami Al-Ghanmi\\"" | sudo tee -a /home/repo/helloworld.git/config

#Fix ownership of repository
sudo chown -R git:www-data /home/repo/helloworld.git
```

> Clone the repository, though empty, and add some code.
>   Ignore the warning about cloning an empty repository.

```
git clone git@$(hostname):/home/repo/helloworld.git
cd helloworld
wget https://raw.github.com/gist/3205222/HelloWorld.cpp
git add HelloWorld.cpp
git commit -m "Initial commit with HelloWorld in C++"
git push origin master
```

Answer (score 19):

You can use a `git-shell-commands` directory to extend `git-shell` with custom commands, these can then be remotely executed using ssh.

For example create `~git/git-shell-commands/newgit` with this content:

```
#!/bin/sh
mkdir -p ~/$1
cd ~/$1
git init --bare
```

Then `chmod +x ~git/git-shell-commands/newgit` to allow execution.

To use it, run:

```
ssh git@server newgit newrepo.git
```

this is enough to create a new bare git repository, it can be cloned using:

```
git clone git@server:newrepo.git
```

Comment: Be careful if using this command on a more public server - if someone connects, and enters `../../../../etc/password`, or something similar, it could screw up your system. Always validate strings/canonicalize paths before operating on them!

Comment: Thx++ Evgeny! Combined with chroot jailed git account, it works like a charm and overpass Tyzoid remark. In my use case, it was ok to add a simple script to list the existing repositories based on your example.

Answer (score 0):

Have look at http://planzero.org/blog/2012/10/24/hosting_an_admin-friendly_git_server_with_git-shell

You can create a git-shell-commands directory in your git user's home directory, then copy in the sample tools from the page to allow creating repo via guest-shell.