# Create new git repository on server - authorizations

Tags: git, ssh

I've setted up a remote repository with git, connecting with ssh.

1. Create project - remote side.
   When I create a project directly from server, then I easily clone (and push/pull operation) it client side.
2. Create project - client side.
   Doing:

   cd testProj
   git init
   git add remote git@:testProj
   git add . && git commit -m "First" && git push origin master

I get error:

> fatal: '/home/git/testProj.git' does not appear to be a git repository
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

How can I grant write-access to some user?

I've already pasted $(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub) on .ssh/authorized_keys server side.

Answer (score 0):

Git over SSH uses the remote servers own authentication/authorization scheme. Does the pushing user have read/write access to the entire testProj directory and all subdirectories?
Moreover; GIT requires a remote repository to be present where you are pointing your remote. In other words, you can't push to a remote server if there is not already a repository present.
You need to cd into the directory where you want your remote first, and execute `git init --bare`

Comment: Hi martin, thanks for answer. Well, let me call R=remote server and B=a generic user. Now, B can login via ssh without inserting psw because I pasted its public key on R. If proj already exist in R, I can work with it, if not exist and I B would create and push it, can't!

Comment: So are you saying that the project does not exist on the remote at all?

Comment: I've updated my answer. It is not so much a solution though. Git simply does not allow you to push a repository to the remote server if you have not initiated a repository there first. Basically, you have to go to the directory and execute 'git init --bare' first.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first log in the server and create the empty repository.

A one liner is

```
ssh git@... git init --bare testProj
```

If you you're using `git-shell` you might need to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21279481/2801377) other question.